# How to fix only last object from loop being duplicated in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

I am working on a project where I loop through a database and add "Profile" objects to an arraylist (searchResults), but for some reason, the last object created from looping through the resultset is duplicated across the arraylist. Please see code snippet below:

```
public static ArrayList<Profile> searchResults;


public void showSearchResults(){
    searchResults = new ArrayList<>();        
    searchResults.clear();

    try {
        // create SQL statement object for query
        statement = Connect.toDatabase();

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery (SQL query here)

        while(resultSet.next()){
            Profile newProfile = new Profile();

            newProfile.setUsername(resultSet.getString("username"));
            newProfile.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
            newProfile.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
            newProfile.setGender(resultSet.getString("gender"));
            newProfile.setAge(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("age")));
            newProfile.setCity(resultSet.getString("city"));                

            searchResults.add(newProfile);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // print out exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // close the connections
        Connect.closeConnection(statement, resultSet);
        showResults = true;
    }
}


public ArrayList<Profile> getSearchResults() {
    return searchResults;
}
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have declared your **edit: attributes in your profile class** as *static*, and as a general rule, **static belongs to a class** while **non-static belongs to an object.**

> Static methods are useful if you have only one instance where you're going to use the method.

Since you have multiple instances here (object) = this isn't what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion did not work. I made the arraylist non-static, but I still encountered the same issue

Comment: @DoubleU difficult to debug without the code for that class. check for static there otherwise edit your answer to show a [reprex]. thanks!

Comment: I guess there's a chance too that your SQL query is returning dups. print those values and make sure maybe

Comment: Thanks so much!! I had static attributes in the Profile class as well. I made those non-static and it worked. Again, thanks so much!!

Comment: @DoubleU I edited my answer - because I was on track but initially incorrect. I believe you could still have the ArrayList itself static, as long as the profile is non-static. Cheers